# Get the second value in a tuple by using the first value in a tuple

Tags: python

As in the title, is there a way to access the second value of a tuple by using the first one?
For example: given a list of tuple: `[('Street', 2), ('Utilities', 3), ('CentralAir', 5)]`, can we access the value '5' by using the index 'CentralAir'?

Comment: `dict([('Street', 2), ('Utilities', 3), ('CentralAir', 5)])['CentralAir']`? As long as the first elements are all hashable, that's likely the easiest way. Or you can iterate over the list until you find the one you want, e.g. the *list comprehension* `[value for key, value in [('Street', 2), ('Utilities', 3), ('CentralAir', 5)] if key == 'CentralAir']` would give you `[5]`.

Comment: No, but you can create a dictionary from that list to do that

Answer (score 4):

For your use case it's more convenient to build a dict to get the value you need.

Example:

```
>>> tuples = [('Street', 2), ('Utilities', 3), ('CentralAir', 5)]
>>> d = dict(tuples)
>>> d
{'Street': 2, 'Utilities': 3, 'CentralAir': 5}
>>> d['CentralAir']
5
```

Comment: What if the OP only wants to do one lookup? Is it still worth creating an entire dictionary?

Comment: Thanks, but are there any other ways to do it without changing it to a dict ?

Comment: @Neil in the worst case to find the value you have to traverse all the list of tuples. This for every time you search for a key. With a dict you traverse the list only once and get a lookup at constant amortized time. So, yes, I'd say it's worth, unless you only need to do it once in the whole program execution life.

Answer (score 3):

a very simple solution

```
ar = [('Street', 2), ('Utilities', 3), ('CentralAir', 5)]
value = next(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'CentralAir', ar))[1] # returns 5
```

Comment: What is the value of casting the filter object to a list when you only want the first element? Why not call next on the iterable?